# Internet Sharing stays connected with phone locked?

Tags: internet-sharing

When I turn on Internet Sharing looks like the connection drops after some seconds past I pin-locked the phone.

I have a Samsung Focus and enabled Internet Sharing with some homebrew procedures.

Anyone have this problem or the connection of Internet Sharing keeps online after pin-lock the phone?

Comment: Is the device on external power at the time?

Comment: Actually it's not. Good point. I need to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't pin-lock my device, but I have happily used  the Internet Connection sharing feature on a HTC Titan after the screen has gone into power save, when the device has been on external power.

Knowing that Windows Phone will disable Wi-Fi to conserve battery when the screen is off, it may just be that you need to connect the phone to an external power source (such as the laptop that the connection is being shared with) to use the connection sharing.

Comment: +1 The only way I've maintained a wi-fi sharing connection with the phone locked is while the phone was connected to a charger.

Comment: There is an app Keep Alive that is suppose to keep your WiFi connection while the screen is locked, even while on battery power.

Comment: Just tried. It works even plugged in the PC.

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy With "+1" did you mean upvate the answer? ;)

Comment: @vitor_canova =-D